# Randomize place where buttons appear?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I couldn't find any tutorials or examples how to do this. It should be easy but I can't figure this out.

So I have RelativeLayout where is many buttons, so how do I make buttons appear random place of that layout every time when activity starts?

eg. First time activity starts one appear bottom right corner and one middle of screen and one top right place. Next time I open same activity those buttons are middle down of layout and upper left corner and so on?

Answer (score 0):

```
Button mButton = new Button(context);
params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(pxVal*2, pxVal);//size of ur button
params.addRule(ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
params.addRule(ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
params.rightMargin = pxMarginH;//u can set ur margin u want, 
params.topMargin = pxMarginH;  //then u can set the button place u want
this.addView(mSearchButton, params);
```

i think this can solve ur problem